# key in object backward

Tags: javascript, object

To loop through an javascript object you can do

```
for(key in object){
   // sth. great...
}
```

Is it possible to loop with this method backward through an object? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Backwards would suggest an order, but objects don't have an order.

Comment: Do you intend to iterate an array backwards? Or actually properties? In the former case, you could just use a downwards counting for loop `for (var i=arr.length-1; i>=0; --i) { do something; }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That won't be possible as

> An ECMAScript object is an **unordered** collection of properties<sub>[ES3 Specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)</sub>
>
> The mechanics and **order** of enumerating the properties (step 6.a in the first algorithm, step 7.a in the second) **is not specified.**
>
> Properties of the object being enumerated may be deleted during enumeration. If a property that has not yet been visited during enumeration is deleted, then it will not be visited. If new properties are added to the object being enumerated during enumeration, the newly added properties are not guaranteed to be visited in the active enumeration. A property name must not be visited more than once in any enumeration.<sub>[ES5 Specs](http://es5.github.io/#x12.6.4)</sub>

<sub>What you could do however, is iterating backwards over the key array of your object. Which does **not** mean that you magically give objects an order.</sub>

```
var obj = {a: 0, b:1, c:2};
for (var keys=Object.keys (obj),key; key = keys.pop() ;) {
    console.log (key) // c, b, a.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no "forwards" and "backwards". Object keys in JavaScript have no order.

While most browsers will loop through them in the order they were added, that's not guaranteed, and is not part of the spec.

So the answer is: no, you can't.

---

If you insist, do this:

```
var keys = [], key, i;

for ( key in object ) {
    object.hasOwnProperty(key) && keys.push(key);
}

i = keys.length;

while ( i-- ) {
    // use object[ keys[i] ]
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MBpcq/

Comment: Nice `&&` trick. Do you have a weekly conditional statement limit that you don't want to exceed? :-)

Comment: @Kos - I just hate nested brackets, and try to avoid them like the plague.

Comment: That's actually a common idiom (?) in JS programming, I've seen it used in many places

Comment: @JosephSilber You're probably a Python fan in this case